# Combinatorial proof of a binomial identiity

Tags: combinatorics

Could anyone advise me how to prove the following using combinatorial proof?

$$r\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ r\end{array}\right)= n\left(\begin{array}{c}n-1\\ r-1\end{array}\right), r \geq 1$$

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Expand combinatorial symbols in terms of factorials.  Identity is immediate.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that is not what I am asking for.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: Suppose you have to choose a group of r people from n people and then choose a leader for that group. this would give you a hint.